# Django project - crispy forms not rendering in the browser

Tags: html, django, forms, rendering

As part of a Django project, I have created the following in the **views.py** file

```
def profile(request):
    u_form =UserUpdateForm()
    p_form =ProfileUpdateForm()

    context={
        'u-form': u_form,
        'p-form': p_form
    }
```

I am now trying to render these forms on the html page **(profile.html)** with the following code:

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Information</legend>
            {{u_form|crispy}}
            {{p_form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update....</button>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Everything else is rendering on the page correctly, except for this bit:

```
            {{u_form|crispy}}
            {{p_form|crispy}}
```

There are no errors on running the server, so I am finding it hard to trouble shoot.

The code in the **forms.py** file is as follows:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm): #form that inherits from the usercreationform
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        #when this form validates it creates a new user
        #type the fields to be shown on your form, in that order.
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']   
"""this gives us a nested name space for configurations and 
        keeps the configs in one place. The model that will be affected is 
        the user model e.g. when we do a form.save it saves it to the user model. 
        And the fields we have are the fields we want on the form. It shows order too. 
        """
#create a model form...this allows us to create a form that#works with a specific database model#
#we want a form that works with our user model
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Profile
        fields=['image']
```

My question is:

Could someone tell me why these additional fields (username, email and image update) are not being shown on the profile html above the 'update' button? In what file have I made the mistake. Note: I'd also appreciate an explanation of the rendering of these u-forms, along with the solution(pointing out my error). I understand that u-form is an instance of UserUpdateForm, but not much else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

context={
        'u-form': u_form,
        'p-form': p_form
    }

You just have a typo. Change the - to _

Comment: Will try this in a minute. How come it didn't come up in an error!?

Comment: Because the renderer won't crash with undefined variables.